# Website is not opening on mobile devices

Tags: web, mobile-website, mobile-devices

My website [FlickrHub](https://flickrhub.com) Was working fine on mobile few days ago but now when i tried to open it it keep giving me error This site can't be reached. Why is that. I don't know what to do The them Im using is (Betube 2.0.2) its responsive and fully mobile friendly. Please help. I'm really confused I haven't installed any plugin or anything either in that time. Only one Propeller ads Official Plugin.

This is what I get on my android phone.

[image: Error this site can't be reached]

Comment: Please do specify the code technology used by you!!!!!

Comment: @Flickr Hub the website you have mentioned is not working on desktop webbrowser also so its not problem of android or mobile.

Comment: It's not working on desktop browser also, so problem is not with the android mobile code may be site issue

Comment: As you can see from your screen shot, flickrhub.com does not resolve to an IP address. You will have to register DNS entries for that name. This is a general networking and infrastructure administration related question and thus off-topic here.